# bootstrap accordion collapsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have tabs menu bottom of the page (footer) which is set to as accordion on responsive (<768px) but it works broken if you try to click accordion links and that's why I want to expanded false on default all accordion must be false. and I'm using [tabCollapse plugin](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse) and it makes my tab menu to accordion on responsive with this code

JS

```
  $('.footer-tabs-to-accordion').tabCollapse();
```

I tried every way on css and jquery but I couldn't achieve because of I'm new in web design and keen on

Comment: please add an example via codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: I add demo link on the top already if you make page responsive you'r gonna see on the footer my accordion

Comment: Each of the accordion links on the inside are href="#" I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: <a href="#">Assos  Otelleri</a> for instance.  What are you trying to make this do?

Comment: it has been added by the plugin

Comment: no I'm talking about footer accordion link if u click first accordion heading you gonna see it's not going to be close

Comment: like this : https://yadi.sk/i/8NixCiWJv8cKh

Comment: Can you remove that active class? class="tab-pane fade in active" That should do it.

Comment: yes but there is no any active class on real document it has been added by jquery plugin on responsive and it has ben not remoeving on jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the class `.collapsed` to the `<a>` that is using the `.accordian-toggle` class in your HTML. Something like this:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">Popüler Oteller</a>
```